# Exit code: 128 Command: git Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository | emailjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, email, yarn-v2

I am trying to add emailjs in the project and the command I am using is `yarn add emailjs/browser`.

Though I am getting the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\sms\My-Portfolio> yarn add emailjs/browser
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/emailjs/browser.git
Directory: C:\Users\sms\My-Portfolio
Output:
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

[image]

I found a solution in case yarn itself is causing issues in installation but I am not able to figure out how to deal with the specific library.
Link - https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the emailjs is [here](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/) for the reference part. 
The correct command to add the emailjs using **yarn** is `yarn add @emailjs/browser` 
And the command to add it using **npm** is `npm i @emailjs/browser` or `npm install @emailjs/browser`.

**Example of successful installation of emailjs using yarn**
[image]